# __add__ two class objects

Tags: python, class, python-2.x

I've been learning Python 2 by searching for tutorials. I'm discovering things about *class*. I have some trouble in `__add__` dunder-method. I don't know how to *add* 2 objects of a class.

To be clearer:

```
class Add_obj:
    def __init__(self, *num):
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Add_obj{}'.format(self.num)

    def __add__(self, other):
        for i in zip(*(self.num + other.num)):
            # and then some codes over here

#when:
obj1 = Add_obj(2, 5)
obj2 = Add_obj(4, 7)
# it should return Add_obj(6, 12)
```

I know it's not the best way to add 2 objects?

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6 while you are still learning - it is an improvement on v2.x - https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: What is `self.num`? A sequence or a single number?  Maybe add a docstring to `__init__`  or the class itself. To start with: maybe just print `i` in the for loop to see what you have - then try to figure out what to do with it.

Comment: One thing to note with your attempt and both answers: when two objects have different lengths of `num`, using `zip` will truncate the longer `num`. So, adding objects of different size will work, but it's unlikely that this is intended behavior. You might want to add an explicit sanity check that the two objects have the same length, or using a solution which fills in 0s as needed to the shorter object.

Comment: Second the advice of learning on Python 3. Learning legacy Python is only something you should be doing if you have a very specific reason. The list of fantastic features in 3.6 compared to 2.7 is very long- you'll enjoy using it much more anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `map` with `operator.add` and iterable unpacking (using `*`) in `__add__`. For example:

```
import operator

class Add_obj:
    def __init__(self, *num):
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Add_obj{}'.format(self.num)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(*map(operator.add, self.num, other.num))
```

And it indeed returns the "expected object":

```
>>> obj1 = Add_obj(2, 5)
>>> obj2 = Add_obj(4, 7)
>>> obj1 + obj2
Add_obj(6, 12)
```

However `map` is not really required it's just a very performant and short way to accomplish this. You could also use a comprehension and `zip` instead:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.__class__(*[num1+num2 for num1, num2 in zip(self.num, other.num)])
```

---

As pointed out in the comments this will also work, but possibly give unexpected (or even wrong) results when the two `Add_obj` have different lengths. If you want to prohibit adding two different sized objects you could raise an Exception instead:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if len(self.num) != len(other.num):
        raise ValueError('cannot two Add_obj with different lengths')
    ...  # use one of the both approaches from above
```

For example:

```
>>> obj1 = Add_obj(2, 5)
>>> obj2 = Add_obj(4, 7, 2)
>>> obj1 + obj2
ValueError: cannot two Add_obj with different lengths
```

Or you could zero-pad the shorter one:

```
from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest  # only zip_longest on Python 3

class Add_obj:

    ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(*[num1+num2 for num1, num2 in zip_longest(self.num, other.num, fillvalue=0)])
```

For example:

```
>>> obj1 = Add_obj(2, 5)
>>> obj2 = Add_obj(4, 7, 2)
>>> obj1 + obj2
Add_obj(6, 12, 2)
```

Comment: You can also use `lambda x, y: x + y` insead of `operator.add` and save one import.

Comment: I chose `map` with `operator.add` because it's fast. Using your `lambda` defeats the performance purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` was a good idea.

```
class Add_obj:
    def __init__(self, *num):
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Add_obj{}'.format(self.num)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Add_obj(*(sum(pair) for pair in zip(self.num, other.num)))


obj1 = Add_obj(2, 5)
obj2 = Add_obj(4, 7)
obj3 = obj1 + obj2

print(obj1)
print(obj2)
print(obj3)
```

Comment: Was going to suggest that exact syntax `sum(pair) for pair in ...` to the other answer, guess I'll +1 this too instead.